# XML to object deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, serialization

I'm trying to Deserilize the following XML

```
    -<Tables>


     -<StaticGroups>


        -<StaticGroup Name="111">


            -<Table>

                <TableName>Table1 Name</TableName>

                <TableTag>Table1 Tag</TableTag>

            </Table>
            -<StaticGroup Name="111.1">


                -<Table>

                    <TableName>Table1.1 Name</TableName>

                    <TableTag>Table1.1 Tag</TableTag>

                </Table>
            </StaticGroup>
        </StaticGroup>
    </StaticGroups>    
</Tables>
```

the nested StaticGroup Name="111.1" doesn't get deserialized for some reason.

The classes are below

```
[XmlRoot("Tables")]
    public class TablesXML
    {
        public TablesXML()
        {
            StaticTablesGroups = new List<StaticTablesGroup>();
        }


        [XmlArray("StaticGroups")]
        [XmlArrayItem("StaticGroup", typeof(StaticTablesGroup))]
        public List<StaticTablesGroup> StaticTablesGroups { get; set; }

    }

    public class StaticTablesGroup
    {
        public StaticTablesGroup()
        {
            GroupTables = new List<GroupTable>();
            StaticTablesGroups = new List<StaticTablesGroup>();
        }

        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //[XmlArray("StaticGroup")]
        [XmlElement("Table", typeof(GroupTable))]
        public List<GroupTable> GroupTables { get; set; }


        [XmlElement("StaticGroup")]
        public List<StaticTablesGroup> StaticTablesGroups { get; set; }   
    }
    public class GroupTable
    {

        [XmlElement("TableName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TableTag")]
        public string Tag { get; set; }


    }
```

first StaticGroup with Name ="111" deserialized successfully, but the nested StaticGroup wihth Name = "111.1" doesn't

What am I doing wrong. Please help

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue.  Perhaps you should also post the deserialization code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might had been an idea to post your deserialization code if your issue is related to deserialization, don't you think?

Anyway, this works fine for me:

```
string xml = "<Tables><StaticGroups><StaticGroup Name=\"111\"><Table><TableName>Table1 Name</TableName><TableTag>Table1 Tag</TableTag></Table><StaticGroup Name=\"111.1\"><Table><TableName>Table1.1 Name</TableName><TableTag>Table1.1 Tag</TableTag></Table></StaticGroup></StaticGroup></StaticGroups></Tables>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TablesXML));
TablesXML tablesXml;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    tablesXml = (TablesXML)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: You absolutely right.  the actual problem is in XAML treeview presentation that doesn't show the nested Group. Really appreciate your help. How can I specify in the TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate how many nested Groups are there if it is unknown in the design time <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding  GroupTables}" DataType="{x:Type data:StaticTablesGroup}">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate><DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:GroupTable}"><Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/> </DataTemplate>

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a closing tag `</Tables>`

Edit: You can always validate your XML to find problems... A quick google search and I found [this one](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) that accused the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You miss the Closing Statement of the "Tables"-XML-object